# PostgreSQL query with window frame running very slowly

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, window-functions, postgresql-performance

So I have a query that I need a column with an aggregate within a determined frame, as example:

```
SUM(subquery1.value) OVER (
    PARTITION BY subquery1.entity 
    ORDER BY subquery1.timestamp 
    ROWS BETWEEN 55 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW
)
```

And so it works, gives me the expected result and it doesn't take up much time. Here's an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of it:
[image]
I know the statics are a bit off, but I'm happy with it.

The problem is that the 55 preceding rows is not really what I want, in fact what I actually want is closer to 50,000 and that's when it gets slower. If i bump the PRECEDING to 555 it already gets much slower, for higher values I haven't waited the run.
[image]

So I don't know whats happening, I have tried the same aggregate directly from a table using 300,000+ rows and it takes less than one second. This example is just over 50k rows so it should be much much faster.

Comment: "I have tried the same aggregate directly from a table using 300,000+ rows and it takes less than one second"  So then, you decided to show us only the part of the query that you already know does not contain the problem?

Comment: Well the analyze seems to point to the problem being the query itself, but you have a point. But idk how the problem would be somewhere else if the somewhere else runs fine.

Comment: The subquery returns less then 10 columns, all data is either integer or double, but it's a relatively large subquery, that also has subqueries in them, JOINS, CTEs an so on. On total there's over 83k characters in the whole query so... it's quite large to analyze it and everything else runs ok, just that part on the question is the problem.
What do you propose?

Comment: A performance question without Postgres version, table definition, query plan (those partial images don't count, provide text instead of images). Why, even without query! And someone voted for it. Remarkable. Consider instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Mate, the instructions call for a full query text as brief as possible. The explanation provided was supposed to highlight what I believe the problem is, to make it brief.
Writing the query and the tables definition would definitely not be brief, as you can see from the obfuscated explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/DdbL
It runs on PostgreSQL Version is 13.3 installed on NVMe, running on a AMD 5600G with 16GB of RAM. I hope this helps.

Comment: The part of the plan you show looks like the window aggregate node has 3 direct child nodes.  But that can't be right, i don't think window agg can take 3 direct children.  What is that plan actually shaped like?  (Your link to depesz isn't working, it just redirects to the front page)

Comment: New link for execution plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/zYtQ
Oh wow, depesz shows that the first two nodes from image are from the CTEs, very interesting, pgAdmin does not do that (as far as I can tell, idk if theres an option to enable it). So that confirms your theory, hope that with the plan it helps to understand. Thanks !